# In The Dybbuk, what is Khonnen wearing when walking in the cemetary at midnight?

Tags: costume, the-dybbuk

In the classic Yiddish film [The Dybbuk](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0030092/), what is Khonnen wearing when walking in the cemetery at midnight? It looks like a skirt, but probably isn't. Is it the end of a long shirt?